# Prove that the probability of having the sine of angle between two random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability, geometry

Let $u_1,u_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two random vectors from the unit sphere. Let $\theta = \angle(u_1,u_2)$ then
$$
\Pr\left(\sin(\theta) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Proof: $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ and the interval which is desired is $[0, \frac{\pi}{4}] \cup [\frac{3\pi}{4}, \pi]$ which is half of the possible range, in terms of interval length.

As this somehow seems surprizing to me, I would like to ask if this is correct ...

Comment: I just added the specification that this is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ...

Comment: @ChrisLewis it seems clear enough we can choose $u_1=e_1$, it’s maybe a little less clear why we can randomly choose a plane and then uniformly randomly choose an angle in said plane.

Comment: @MW we're not randomly choosing a plane, though; the two vectors define a plane (unless one is a scalar multiple of the other). There is potentially an issue, as there always is, with how the vectors are chosen in the first place; but as long as it's a uniform distribution over the surface of the sphere it's OK.

Comment: @ChrisLewis. Ok, I think I mistakenly presumed you were doing some different argument.  Is it really obvious the angle is uniformly distributed in this instance?  I’m somehow not making the connection that “uniform over surface area” implies “uniform angle”.  It might be obvious and I’m just being obtuse at the moment

Comment: @ChrisLewis In fact it seems false, since a small patch of $\epsilon$ radians near $e_1$ has area roughly $\pi \epsilon^2$, but the tube describing $\pi/2+-\epsilon$ Radians is much larger at roughly $4\pi\epsilon$. (In $\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: @MW Argh, actually, I'm completely wrong!!!! Sorry for the confusion. I can't edit my comments now so will delete and leave this as a correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on $n$ and what you mean by "random".

I assume random means sampling the vectors according to the standard (hyper)surface area (or arc-length when $n=2$).

When $n=2$, it's easy to see this is true. But even for $n=3$, this is false.

By symmetry, we may assume the first vector is $(0, 0, 1)$, and the second vector is sampled from the top of the sphere $\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\ge 0\}$. It's clear that $\sin(\theta)\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is equivalent to $z=\cos(\theta)\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. It's [well-known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesHat-BoxTheorem.html) (even to Archimedes) that the surface area of a spherical hat is a linear function of $z$.

Hence the probability is $$1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\approx0.29<0.5$$

Comment: Just minor nitpick, I think you mean it’s true for $n=2$ and false when $n\neq 2$, since we are considering $\mathbb S^{n-1}$

Comment: Is it possible to choose the vectors to assure uniform distribution of the angle?

Comment: @MW Thank you! Corrected. Too used to the dimensions of the manifold.

Comment: @CMarius Not really... if so, the measure would not be $SO(3)$-invariant, that is some points will have higher probability density than others